# build a new function as afterSave() Yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am building a shoping cart in Yii. Now I want to buid a function with name is afterCharged() the same as afterSave(). So how to can do it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michiel said you should use an event in your method

```
function charge(){ 
    //Perform charge related actions
    $this->onCharge(new CEvent($this));
    //... maybe some code over here after raising the event
}

public function onCharge($event){
    $this->raiseEvent('onCharge', $event);
}
```

Now you have to catch the raised event. So in this component you'll declare which class and which mehod need to catch it (for example in the `init` method)

```
//OtherClass need to catch the the charge event
$callback = array(new OtherClass,'afterCharge')
$component->onCharge = $callback;
```

So the method `afterCharge` of `OtherClass` will be called when `charge()` is executed.

By the way, the method afterCharge must have the following signature

```
function afterCharge($event) {
}
```

Sources:

- [The wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/327/events-explained/)
- [Yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-event)

Comment: Also, I have a question : $component is global variable. Thank you very much

Comment: No, this is the class that throw the event so you could replace it by $this

Comment: And one question anymore:). So I can use event in Controller class ?

Comment: Hum yeah i think. If i remember well events are implemented in CComponent so every class who inherit from it can use events. And CControler extends CComponent so it should work :-)